# How to get text from image in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ocr

In my project I need to get text from an image. Actually I want to get information(text) from a business card. I need to implement OCR in my project.I've used an open source library [Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) But its not accurate. Please tell me about any good library which could be useful.

Comment: I think you'll need to show more research than this.  Maybe give it a go and then post your code and we'll help as much as we can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think OpenCV is enough for you task. 
 Official manual: [http://docs.opencv.org/](https://github.com/pablosproject/iPhone-OCR-Tesseract-and-OpenCV)

Other examples: [github](https://github.com/pablosproject/iPhone-OCR-Tesseract-and-OpenCV)

And working example using opencv and Tesseract together [iPhone-OCR](https://github.com/pablosproject/iPhone-OCR-Tesseract-and-OpenCV)

Comment: I don't want to edit my image actually. I want to get text from image of a business card etc. I need to use OCR. But I don't know how to use.

Comment: Here is an example of using opencv and Tesseract together: https://github.com/pablosproject/iPhone-OCR-Tesseract-and-OpenCV